# OpenCV C++ with extern "C"

Tags: c++, c, opencv, compilation, linker

I'm currently trying to make a program that uses openCV for taking a picture from a webcam and performing graphical operations to find an area in openCV and then passing it to a .c program which just sends the information to a server via port programming.

my problem is that even though I created a .h file for the functions I used in the openCV .cpp code and included it in my .c, there's still an error saying `error: expected ‘)’ before ‘&’ token`

here is my simpleIS.h:

```
int captureimg();
int backgroundsub();
void noisesuppression(Mat &ptr);
void simplegetarea(Mat &img);

extern int area1,area2,area3,area4;
```

any ideas?

Comment: There are no references in C. Use pointers or value instead.

Comment: Also don't forget that compiled C/C++ functions/variables resolve into different symbol names. See `extern "C"` for more info

Comment: its easier to compile c code as c++ than the other way around

Comment: Hi, how can C support "Mat" from openCV??

Comment: as long as you are including it the header in c, you cannot use cpp structures in the header file but iplimage and mat are small header structures that can be converted to each other quickly. so in your .cpp file which contains the implementation, you would do this conversion from c structure to cpp structure. but i think the program structure is looking a bit strange if your c implementation needs to pass the mat structure back to cpp...does the c side really need to know things about opencv? if it's just small info transfer, maybe just create a small struct container and pass it around

Comment: I just call some functions from my openCV code in my C file, but the passed data from the openCV is just the `int` type area. I'm having troubles with compiling and linking the two together.

what I did was I compiled my .c by:
`gcc -c code1.c`
then compiled my .cpp(openCV code) by:
`gcc -c simpleIS.cpp -I /usr/local/include/opencv`

then integrated the two by
`gcc -o this client.o simpleIS.o -I /usr/local/include/opencv -L /usr/local/include/opencv /usr/local/include/opencv2/core`
which still gives me errors

Comment: @rerun in the case of openCV .cpp code, how would I do it? any clues?

Answer (score 2):

You're going to have to wrap the functions you need in other C++ functions, and have those functions have extern "C" linkage.  You're also going to have to have C data structures that hold the stuff you will need to create the C++ classes. Call the wrapper functions from C.

E.g., if you have a cpp function like this:

```
int im_a_cxx_function(int , some_type, another_type &);
```

You make a wrapper function :

```
extern "C" int im_a_cxx_wrapper_function(int i, 
                                          struct some_C_type *st_C, 
                                          struct another_C_type *at_C)
{
    some_type st;
    another_type at;

    set_some_type(&st,  st_C);
    set_another_type(&at, at_C);

    return im_a_cxx_function(i, st, at);
}
```

Then, in the header for your wrapper functions:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
int im_a_cxx_wrapper_function(int i, struct some_C_type *st_C, 
                               struct another_C_type *at_C);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Then, you include the header for your wrapper functions in your .c file, and call the the wrapper function normally.  The main this is that you can't call a function without extern "C" from C due to name mangling, and since you aren't in control of the library functions, you have to wrap them up.  You can also hold opaque pointers to C++ types, but since you can't use constructors, you'll generally have to at least write factory and delete functions for them.

Answer (score 0):

Following shoud work. Your `example.h` file:

```
#pragma once

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
    int __declspec(dllexport) main(int argc, char** argv); // just modify this line !!!
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

In your `example.cpp` file, change only:

```
extern "C" int main(int argc, char** argv)
```

You might want to modify function name for `main()` or change parameters.